# Postman simulation of login website with invisible reCaptcha

Tags: http, authentication, postman, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am trying to simulate the login process of a website that has invisible recaptcha using Postman. I used both chrome DevTools and interceptor feature of the Postman. I also used the capture cookies feature in Postman to ensure I have the same cookies as in Chrome. The POST request for login api of the website has a JSON body of something like below:

{"userName":"myusermane","password":"mypassword","captchaResponse":"03AGdBq25SXrvrLWv3VbhyNPYCccO62Scf5reo04IeLNloKGo7ND1TcX7mg67fG-tL_0w1E7urn0MvoCJvdl6c5SBDloPXaeHiTnDMsjIgEGrvLjPbdsZ8U6vpL8VuqX1DZgGFRXXj_97ra1ZgYpuQykxnCEtgXQXwVqF5IbHyGj7MwtzM0jvT1wHdfFCDDJ3o9Z7edgUfHZeHHjfmMI_s1j5wZY2Lvp9XEGYdA9kmR5kZxu_CaGZ9i9rll8nY-GBqC4wWNuazB0l9F7k3R0ragTL9eoNawsdUP2l8nBvpR0dhWf476KqBgN7fE7aIj6HNQbCzRltgiUJeUh5RUmZk_XeUdN2hNhTAhfK8cwH1crn-bddCQ9J4ZJtFOcZ8qTYZbf6PWp1Hw8lX"}

The problem is while the login is successful in Chrome, the exact same request in Postman fails. Why is this happening? I am thinking that there might be something with invisible recaptcha fundamental that I do not understand. Hope someone can figure it out

Comment: Sounds like reCAPTCHA is working as intended. What you're trying to do is what it's meant to keep people from doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is while the login is successful in Chrome, the exact same request in Postman fails. Why is this happening?

This is the purpose of a Captcha: it prevents automated logins, allowing only a human to log in.

In other words, this is happening because it is exactly what is supposed to be happening.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this captchaResponse can only be used once. The thing is I am trying to make a simple IOS app that need to have a login feature to this website. When user click login, the login process should be the same as browser login. How can I do that?

Comment: I noticed that to get this one time captchaResponse, I need to do GET of https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6LdRb64UAAAAAM-4wtTJPQ2z8dQ6SbS14ZhA4WRM&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9mb3J1bXMuaHVhcmVuLnVzOjQ0Mw..&hl=en&v=oqtdXEs9TE9ZUAIhXNz5JBt_&size=invisible&cb=rk4892u75fo9    in which I know how to get k= and v= by parsing the previous response. But I did not find the parameter co= and cb= anywhere in any response? Does it related to some javascript called during the multiple request?

Comment: Thanks for your answer to this question anyway. But how to make a login in IOS app the same as browser login may need a lot extra work